# How to force checkbox type in Symfony sending false value if it is't checked?

Tags: symfony

Here is a list of all options in checkbox type https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#empty-data

But I couldn't find exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you trying to make a GET request? In this case, `false` is translated as `''` (empty space).
2. Are you trying to make a POST request? Good. Is your formed linked to an entity / model? 
   2.1. If yes, just set that property as `bool` and by default, if is not marked it will be `false`.
   2.1. If no, after request get your property like this: `$form->get('property_name')->getData()` and validate it with `empty()` function.

More details here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms